# Cisco ASA 5500 -- List of outbound connections?

Tags: networking, firewall, cisco, cisco-asa, sniffing

Is there a command or GUI option to get a list of outbound connections. Ideally, I'd like to know the internal IP address, the external IP address, and the remote port used.

I don't need a lot of history, but an hour or two is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try... `sh conn`. This show active connections.

```
asa# sh conn ?

  address        Enter this keyword to specify IP address
  all            Enter this keyword to show conns including to-the-box and
                 from-the-box
  count          Enter this keyword to show conn count only
  detail         Enter this keyword to show conn in detail
  long           Enter this keyword to show conn in long format
  port           Enter this keyword to specify port
  protocol       Enter this keyword to specify conn protocol
  state          Enter this keyword to specify conn state
  user           Enter this keyword to specify conn user
  user-group     Enter this keyword to specify conn user group
  user-identity  Enter this keyword to show user names
  |              Output modifiers
  <cr>
```